# How to turn off debug mode in cakePHP based on some condition in controller function

Tags: cakephp

I am working with CakePHP 3.7. I am trying to send email via one function. But problem is, while I want to send email it shows me one error like this.

`Undefined index: debugKitLog [ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Mailer\Transport\DebugKitTransport.php, line 37]`

I have solved this error by disabling debugger from `bootstrap.php`. But while I am working on my system, this debugger is needed. So it takes time to enable and disable again and again. For that reason I want to turn of this debugger once this email sending function is called. And once email is sent, then I want to enable this debugger again. 
Here is the code that I have disabled in `bootstrap.php` for sending email.

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
   Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', true);
   Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

But I want not to disable it in `bootstrap.php`. For this, here is the bellow function what I have tried.

```
public function sendEmail($toEmail){
Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', false);
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => false]);
$emailAddress = new Email();
$emailAddress->from($this->Auth->user('email'))
->to($toEmail)
->emailFormat('html')
->template('modulePermissionRequest')
->subject("Module access request from SW")
->setViewVars(['assignModuleLink' => 'link'])
->setViewVars(['sentBy' => $this->Auth->user('first_name') . ' ' . $this->Auth->user('last_name')])
->setViewVars(['moduleName' => 'name'])
->send();
Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', true);
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

With above function this `Undefined index: debugKitLog [ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Mailer\Transport\DebugKitTransport.php, line 37]` issue is not showing but still email also not sending.

Comment: So, when you are testing, you still want emails to be sent out? And you want everything else about DebugKit enabled, just not the way that it intercepts and logs emails?

Comment: Yes. I just want to disable this debug kit for few second (to send email). And once email is sent I want to enable it again.

Comment: Check the [DebugKit configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html#configuration). Seems that you can disable individual panels, and I think (though only a cursory look at the code) that disabling the Mail panel would mean that the DebugKit transport isn't used, so it should use your regular email transport instead.